# Can someone help me with an array based Binary Search Tree C++?

Tags: c++

This what i have so far.

```
void BST::insert(const data& aData)
{
    if ( items[root_index].empty ) 
    {
        items[root_index].theData = aData;// Get the data.
        items[root_index].empty = false;
        oldRoot.theData = aData;
    }  
    else  
    {   
        if ( aData < items[root_index].theData )
        {
            leftChild = root_index * 2;
            if ( items[leftChild].empty )
            {
                items[leftChild].theData = aData;
                items[leftChild].empty = false;
            }
            else 
            {
              root_index++;
              items[root_index].theData = items[leftChild].theData;                          
                                   items[root_index].empty = false;
              this->insert(aData);
            }
        }
         else if ( items[root_index].theData < aData )
         {
            rightChild = root_index * 2 + 1;
            if ( items[rightChild].empty )
            {
                items[rightChild].theData = aData;
                items[rightChild].empty = false;
            }
            else
            {//this where the problem is for "Z" insertion
                root_index++;
                items[root_index].theData = items[rightChild].theData;
                items[root_index].empty = false;
                this->insert(aData);
            }
        }
        else return;
    }
    items[1].theData = oldRoot.theData;
}
```

and the constructor:

```
BST::BST(int capacity) : items(new item[capacity]), size(0),
leftChild(0), rightChild(0), root_index(1)
{
     items->empty = true;
     maxSize = capacity-1;
}
```

It doesnt work. I dont know why. I cant seem to write the code to make it balanced. What I have so far is a tree that resembles:

```
       R
      /
     A
      \
       F
```

When inserting, "R", "A", and "F", so when i try to insert "Z" it becomes F's right child. But it should really be the root's right child:

```
       R
      / \
     A   Z
      \
       F
```

Can someone help me make it like that?

Comment: First things first. Your RAF tree is not balanced. A balanced version of that would have rotated A up to the root, having F in the left node and R in the right node. Binary trees are not necessarily balanced trees.

Comment: Care to discuss how this relates to your earlier question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1739067/inserting-into-an-array-based-binary-search-tree-c ?

Comment: ...and here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1736872/array-based-binary-search-tree-c

Comment: ...and here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1733211/im-stuck-with-filling-my-array-based-bst-in-c

Comment: ...and here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1712017/binary-search-tree-array-imp-c

Comment: i didnt get the answer i was looking for.

Comment: *"How can i easily fix that?"* That is non-trivial in an array-based implementation. Do you understand how it would be done in a pointer based tree? Can you see why the array case is different?

Comment: Since this problem looks like homework, and since you seem to be having a rough time with it, might I recommend that you speak to your instructor or TA for help?  They should be willing to help you work through the issues you are having and point you in the right direction (though, admittedly, I've had some professors who were less than helpful).  It's just a suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

I could be missing something, but the code just looks like all kinds of messed up. The `root_index++`, the recursive call to `insert()` after you add the data to the tree... You might want to go back to the drawing board on this one.

If you're going for a complete binary search tree (which is the main reason for using an array), you can append new elements to the array and move elements that break the tree order invariants (left descendents < node and node < right descendents) up the tree.